# asp.net webservice get terminated when have & at parameter?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, json, web-services

I have an iPhone application through which I call asp.net webservice with json. It works fine with all data. But when I try to & in any data it throws server error as below

```
 System.ArgumentException: Unterminated string passed in. (55): {&quot;UserId&quot;:&quot;somebody@somebody.com&quot;,&quot;FirstName&quot;:&quot;somebody
   at ProjectName.ProjectWebService.AuthenticationService.UserRegistration(String jsonText) in C:\Users\mkariya\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectNames\MeaNexusWebService\AuthenticationService.asmx.cs:line 555
```

Data which I passed to this web service is as below

> "UserId":"somebody@somebody.com","FirstName":"somebody&fname","City":"Ahmedabad","LastName":"somebodylname","State":"Gujarat","Country":"India","Password":"admin1!"}

in which **FirstName** has value **somebody&fname**, so issue occurs at that place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand. Use the following instead of the "&" character:

```
\u0026
```

Comment: Wippy, thanks it works for me I used **jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"\\u0026"];** but don't you think it's improper way of coding. Did you know about other characters which can create this type of issues...!?!

Comment: Pleasure. Quotes, double quotes and backslashes to name but a few. I'm sure you'll be able to find a more complete list if you google "javascript escape characters"

Answer (score 0):

try escape() function in javascript before passing the variable and 
HttpUtility.UrlDecode() at server side